# Is there any way for finding the Overlapping Time in table Workorder using DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, overlap

I want to make a report using DB2 SQL that will show the list of duration (hours) between 15th and 17th May. The current list look like this:

[click here to view the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGSv4.png)

As you can see, from `WO-391296` (second row) it has overlapping time in `ACTSTART` and `ACTFINISH`.

I've already tried the Overlaps function. This is my query :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workorder a,
    workorder b
WHERE
    a.wonum <> b.WONUM
    AND (a.ACTSTART, a.ACTFINISH) OVERLAPS (b.ACTSTART, b.ACTFINISH)
    AND DATE(a.ACTSTART) = '2019-05-15'
    AND DATE(a.ACTFINISH) = '2019-05-17'
    AND a.assetnum = 'A0000004'
    AND DATE(b.ACTSTART) = '2019-05-15'
    AND DATE(b.ACTFINISH) = '2019-05-17'
    AND b.assetnum = 'A0000004' ;
```

But it doesn't work and just giving me the error message.:

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "OVERLAPS" was found following "TSTART, a.ACTFINISH)".  Expected tokens may include:  "IN".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.64.114

Here's my actual full query :

```
SELECT assetnum, wonum, worktype, actstart, actfinish, 
    (DAY(ACTFINISH-ACTSTART)*24 + HOUR(ACTFINISH-ACTSTART)) + FLOAT(MINUTE(ACTFINISH-ACTSTART))/60 AS wotime 
FROM ( 
    SELECT assetnum, wonum, WORKTYPE, ACTSTART, 
        (CASE WHEN ACTFINISH IS NULL THEN '2019-05-17-24.00.00' ELSE ACTFINISH END) AS ACTFINISH 
    FROM workorder ast 
    WHERE istask=0 AND siteid = 'SBY' AND WORKTYPE = 'CM' AND
        (ast.assetnum = 'A0000004' or 
         assetnum in (select distinct assetnum from asset ast where ast.parent = 'A0000004') or 
         assetnum in (select distinct assetnum from asset ast where ast.parent 
                  in (select distinct assetnum from asset ast where ast.parent = 'A0000004'))) AND 
        ( 
            (status IN ('COMP', 'CONFIRM', 'CLOSE') AND 
            (date(ACTFINISH) BETWEEN '2019-05-15' and '2019-05-17')) OR 
            (status IN ('INPRG', 'COMP', 'CONFIRM', 'CLOSE') AND 
            (date(ACTSTART) <= '2019-05-17' AND (date(ACTFINISH) > '2019-05-17' OR ACTFINISH IS null))) 
        ) 
);
```

The actual total duration of this list is 6 hours which is **wrong**, because I don't want to `SUM` the overlapping time.

So, the final result must be 3.5 hours (without `WO-391296`).

Answer (score 0):

2 Intervals overlap if:
`start of the 1-st is <= of end of the 2-nd`
and
`start of the 2-nd is <= of end of the 1-st`

```
create or replace function overlaps_dates (a_from date, a_to date, b_from date, b_to date)
returns int
deterministic
no external action
contains sql
return case when min(a_from, a_to) <= max(b_from, b_to) and min(b_from, b_to) <= max(a_from, a_to) then 1 else 0 end;
```

Comment: Hi Mark. I just put it into WHERE clause and change the IF statement you said to AND. Because DB2 can't read IF statement. They used CASE WHEN instead of IF. And CASE WHEN as long as I know, is placed in SELECT. Not WHERE. I've tried your suggestion, but the result still not getting the Overlap. Thank you btw :D

Comment: You don’t have to put the expression after “if” in my post, if you are sure, that end date is not less then start date in your data. Just use first pair of inequalities before “if”.